# How this electric lighter works?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, light, arc

I have seen this type of electric lighter : 
[image: Electric lighter]
But I don't really understand why the electric arcs are crossing each other instead of going straight.
How is it possible?

Comment: By energizing only 1 pair of electrodes at a time you can get the arc to jump diagonally. Switch between electrode pairs quickly and it will appear that you get a X in the center.

Comment: Or just two completely separate ignition coils, even easier, also easier on the timing if you'd alternate anyway.

Comment: I am guessing you could do that with a single HV transformer output by having both arcs in parallel but with a diode in series on each but in opposite directions, so both arcs fire in alternation.

Comment: @Asmyldof Is it really possible without alternate the two arcs with two separate ignition coils doing this? Is it impossible for one arc to go straight into the other?

Comment: @TWiz If you have a single HV transformer you can only have one arc no? Or a single HV transformer with two outputs?

Comment: Tagadac - Reading and understanding before asking more helps us all. See what Twiz said about diodes.  Two isolated windings on one transformer would also work. If the windings are isolated on one transformer OR isolated on two transformers there would be no voltage available to drive the arc between the two isolated circuits - unless gas ionisation caused a path to form - which would be a neat trick to play with.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I see, thank your for your illumination.